# Is the "least non-negative residue" of $b^p \pmod{m}$ just $b^p \pmod{m}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm just wondering if the "least non-negative residue" of $b^p \pmod{m}$ is just $b^p \pmod{m}$ itself. What is the "least non-negative residue"? How is it found? Is this how it is found? Just by finding $b^p \pmod{m}$?

Comment: http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/Residue.html

Comment: There two unfortunately very similar notations, one most common in Computer Science, and the other in number theory. In Computer Science, $x\bmod m$ is used to denote the least non-negative residue of $x$ modulo $m$. In number theory, that notation is seldom used, indeed there is no specific symbol for the least non-negative residue. The most one can say is that it is the smallest non-negative $y$ such that $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a way of being clear what is wanted.  Many people think $\text{anything} \pmod m$ is some element of $\{0,1,2,\ldots,m-1\}$  Others think it is a whole equivalence class like $\{\ldots,-2m,-m,0,m,2m,\ldots\}$.  It is asking for the first.